# php array item separate to another array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have an array.In this array have 156 item.my desired  output format is

```
{
    "status": "OK",
    "message": "Data Show Successful",
    "allresult": [
        {
            "id": "",
            "title": "Yes/No",
            "details": "Text"
        }
}
```

First 0-19 column data shows like
"status": "OK",
 "message": "Data Show Successful",

Also last 2 column value shows same
Now main complex is 
Column 20 to 155
These data goes to  allresult array
Here every 9 column shows like

```
{
    "id": "",
    "title": "Yes/No",
    "details": "Text"
}
```

Lets describe
Column 20 to 155 have same type data 
In pair of every 9 column have same type data

- possession
- possession___length
- open_cary
- open_carry_length
- concealed
- concealed_length
- concealed_w__ccw_required
- concealed_w__ccw_required_length
- notes

now our allresult output look like for 20 to 37 number columns

```
"allresult": [
    {
       " possession": "here value of 20",
       "possession___length": " here value of 21",
       " open_cary ": " here value of 22 "
       Up to notes
    },
    {
        " possession": "here value of 29",
        "possession___length": " here value of 30",
        " open_cary ": " here value of 31"
       Up to notes
    }
}
```

I can retrieve all data and can show it json array output but  cant separate Column 20 to 155 data for every 9 column

retrieve all data

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{
    $info[]=$row;
}

$output = array( 'result' =>$info);

echo json_encode($output);
```

Comment: Look into `array_slice()` http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php

Comment: how can i slice my main array after every 9? any example @JayBlanchard

Answer (score 0):

What about array_chunk()? It lets you set the size of each chunk

> array_chunk — Split an array into chunks
>
> Description
>
> array array_chunk ( array $array , int $size [, bool $preserve_keys =
>   false ] ) Chunks an array into arrays with size elements. The last
>   chunk may contain less than size elements.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php